# Multiple js files in an html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing some codes in P5JS. And I want to add multiple JS files to my HTML page. But when I do that, only the last one is displayed on the page. How can I show all of them?! And how can I style each one? For example I want to show one of them on top of the page, then have some HTML files or texts or whatever, then another JS file below them. How can style them using CSS? I have already linked the CSS file to the HTML page.

[The site didn't allow me to paste the code the way I wanted so I uploaded the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeIIz.png)

Thanks..

Comment: Can you post your code? I need to see what it looks like

Comment: I uploaded the picture of my codes. Thanks.

Comment: Still not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting to display the contents of the javascript files in the web browser, so that when people visit you page, they see the javascript source code?

Comment: Those JS files are actually some animations I want to use on my page.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of the js files either in the head section:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src=script1.js></script>
<script src=script2.js></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can put it at the bottom of the file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src=script1.js></script>
<script src=script2.js></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same. Only shows the second one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to add multiple p5js sketches to one HTML document you could create p5 instances to keep all variables out of the global scope of your page.

Example if the following was saved as `'sketch.js'`:

```
var sketch = function( p ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x,y,50,50);
   };
};

var myp5 = new p5(sketch);
```

and then you would import the sketch and use it in a div in your HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sketch"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You would then repeat for other sketches. You can even have multiple p5js sketches in one js file.

With the code for your sketches and html this would probably be fairly quick to resolve.